# Merge two data by a similar name?

Tags: r, merge

Is it possible to merge two datasets by columns with similar names?

```
country <- c("United States of America", "China", "Russia Federation")
scores <- c(1, 2, 3)
df.1 <- cbind(country, scores)

country <- c("United States", "China", "Russians")
scores <- c(3, 2, 1)
df.2 <- cbind(country, scores)

unsucessful.merge <- merge(df.1, df.2, by=c("country"))
unsucessful.merge
>   country scores.x scores.y
> 1   China        2        2
```

As you can see, after merging, U.S. and Russia are dropped, and we are left with China. I want the data frame to look like this:

```
successful.merge
>                    country scores.x scores.y
> 1                    China        2        2
> 2        Russia Federation        3        1
> 3 United States of America        1        3
```

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/countrycode/countrycode.pdf

Comment: I think @Masoud has the right idea. Map all the different names back to a code and then merge on that. There are packages that can deal with some fuzziness in joining, like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin - but obviously this won't deal with comparing cases like `DPRK / North Korea` or `Myanmar / Burma` where abbreviations or historical names are not even remotely alike.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I wonder if this dataframe were classifying something else, would there be a way to merge two data sets by similar names.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know all the country name permutations you can use regular expressions.

```
df.1 <- apply(df.1,2,function(x) gsub(".*United States.*|USA","United States",x,ignore.case=T))
df.1 <- apply(df.1,2,function(x) gsub(".*Russia.*","Russia",x,ignore.case=T))
df.2 <- apply(df.2,2,function(x) gsub(".*United States.*|USA","United States",x,ignore.case=T))
df.2 <- apply(df.2,2,function(x) gsub(".*Russia.*","Russia",x,ignore.case=T))
merge(df.1, df.2, by=c("country"))
        country scores.x scores.y
1         China        2        2
2        Russia        3        1
3 United States        1        3
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but `apply(df.1, 2, ...)` is not ideal as it will convert every variable to the same type in `df.1`. It will also replace data in columns of `df.1` other than the `country` column. Admittedly, OP is already unwisely using a character matrix because of `cbind(country, scores)` instead of `data.frame(country, scores)`, but `apply` is unnecessary. Just `df.1[,"country"] <- gsub(find, replace, df.1[,"country"])` would be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for the hard work. I appreciate it very much. It's late right now, so I will take a look at it tomorrow. Once again, much appreciated. I upvoted the downvote to balance the negativity ++